# Ruby command line gem search returns no results

Tags: rubygems

I'm trying to search remote gems as described in the [RubyGems guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/), but the following command searches local gems on my system:

```
$ gem search ^rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

What's likely to cause this, how might I diagnose and fix it? I'm using RVM.

**Update**:

- Ruby version  1.9.3p194
- RubyGems version 1.8.24
- RVM version 1.22.13

Comment: what shell are you using?  have you tried gem search \^rails does that make a difference. also have version of gem?

Comment: Which version of Rubygems are you using?

Comment: bash shell, no difference with the backslash, gem version 1.8.24

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `gem search` defaults to searching remotely only from version 1.8.25 onward. To search remote gems with older versions you have to use the `-r` (or `--remote`) option:

```
$ gem --version
1.8.23
$ gem search ^rails
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
...
$ gem search -r ^rails
** REMOTE GEMS ***
...
```

See `gem help search` and the [Rubygems changelog](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/History.txt) for more informations.

Answer (score 2):

first install bundle then try this command. hope this works.

```
 $rvm 1.9.3
 $gem install rails
 $gem search ^rails
```

Comment: before giving this command set your rvm like i am using ruby 1.9.3 , so i use command rvm 1.9.3 . after that use both above command . i am sure this works.

Comment: There's no gemfile, so running `bundle install` doesn't do anything.

Comment: then you check you have rails installed properly. if not then install it with gem install rails then try...

Comment: then you check you have rails installed properly with ($rails -v). if not then install it with ($gem install rails) then try...ignore first comment.

Comment: Thanks but the issue I was looking to fix was with searching for remote gems, not rails. The accepted answer has fixed it for me.

Comment: @OllieGlass you welcome. I think i missunderstand your question.